# Double loop on a list and a dataframe python panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to create a new dataframe based on a list and a dataframe

The list :

```
list_ge =  ["EG1", "EG2, EG5", "EG6", "EG4, EG3"]
```

the dataframe :

```
        A1        B2      
0       EG1       DE   
1       EG1       DZ    
2       EG1       DA  
3       EG2       AC     
4       EG3       RC       
5       EG3       UC     
6       EG4       TC       
7       EG5       VC 
8       EG6       WC
9       EG6       XC
```

The result I expect :

```
        list_ge   A1        B2      
0       EG1       EG1       DE   
1                 EG1       DZ    
2                 EG1       DA  
3       EG2       EG2       AC     
4       EG5       EG5       VC       
5       EG6       EG6       WC     
6                 EG6       XC       
7       EG4       EG4       TC
6       EG3       EG3       RC       
7                 EG3       UC
```

My code look like this, I try to create my new dataframe but I don't know how to join or merge my list of ge and my df_extract at the end ; I try with join but it is not working

```
list_ge =  ["EG1", "EG2, EG5", "EG6", "EG4, EG3"]
df1 = pandas.read_csv(file1,sep="\t",header=None)
csvFile = open('newfile.csv', 'w')
for line in liste: 
        df_extract = [] 
        ec_id_list = line.split(',')
        for famille in line.split(','):
                extract_line=df1[df1[0].str.match(famille)]
                df_extract.append([extract_line, extract_line + 1])
        g= "\t".join([";".join(ec_id_list), ";".join(str(v) for v in df_extract)])
        csvFile.write(g+"\n")
csvFile.close()
```

Comment: you do not use poandas...

Comment: my bad ........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
list_ge =  ["EG1", "EG2", "EG5", "EG6", "EG4", "EG3"]
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'list_ge':list_ge}).merge(df, left_on='list_ge', right_on='A1')
df_out['list_ge'] = df_out['list_ge'].mask(df_out['list_ge'].duplicated(),'')
df_out
```

Output:

```
  list_ge   A1  B2
0     EG1  EG1  DE
1          EG1  DZ
2          EG1  DA
3     EG2  EG2  AC
4     EG5  EG5  VC
5     EG6  EG6  WC
6          EG6  XC
7     EG4  EG4  TC
8     EG3  EG3  RC
9          EG3  UC
```

Convert your list in to a dataframe and join that dataframe to the origin, then mask duplicates of 'list_ge'.